# SQL Server - How To Properly Update Table With User Defined Function In Update Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have an issue attempting to update a table using a user defined function in the update statement.

I have greatly simplified my existing SQL, and provided some sample code to show the issue that I am seeing.

I start off with 300 rows in a test table all with the same timestamp value

I need to group the 300 rows in MyTestTable into 3 sets of 100 rows with the same timestamp

What I want to see is something like this:

```
Timestamp               Count   
2016-04-01 15:51:00     100  
2016-04-01 15:52:00     100  
2016-04-01 15:53:00     100
```

What I'm seeing right now is all 300 rows updated with the **same** timestamp:

```
Timestamp               Count  
2016-04-01 15:51:00     300
```

What is the best way to formulate this query??

Below is some simplified sample code that reproduces the problem

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTestTable]
(
    [ID] [int],
    [Timestamp] [smalldatetime]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_MyTestFunction]
     (@StartTime smalldatetime,
      @EndTime smalldatetime,
      @RandomNumberOfSeconds int)
RETURNS smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Timestamp SMALLDATETIME

    -- Find an existing Timestamp between @StartTime and @EndTime in the MyTestTable
    -- with less than 100 rows with that timestamp
    SET @Timestamp = (SELECT TOP 1 [Timestamp] 
                      FROM MyTestTable
                      WHERE [Timestamp] BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime
                      GROUP BY [Timestamp]
                      HAVING COUNT(*) < 100)

    -- If no row found with timestamp between @StartTime and @EndTime
    -- or no timestamp found which has less than 100 rows with that timestamp
    -- Create a timestamp with a time somewhere between @StartTime and @EndTime
    if (@Timestamp is null)
    begin
        set @Timestamp = dateadd(ss, @RandomNumberOfSeconds, @StartTime)
    end

    return @Timestamp
END
GO

declare @Counter int
set @Counter = 0

-- Populate the test table with 300 rows, all initially with the same timestamp value
while @Counter < 300
begin
    insert MyTestTable (ID, [Timestamp]) values (@Counter, 'April 1, 2016')
    set @Counter = @Counter + 1
end

declare @StartTime smalldatetime
declare @EndTime smalldatetime
declare @RandomNumberOfSeconds float
set @RandomNumberOfSeconds = 60

set @StartTime = current_timestamp
set @EndTime = dateadd(minute, 30, @StartTime)

update MyTestTable
   set [Timestamp] = dbo.fn_MyTestFunction(@StartTime, @EndTime, @RandomNumberOfSeconds)

select [Timestamp], count(*) as "Count"
from MyTestTable
group by [Timestamp]
```

Answer (score 3):

An `update` statement completes as a single transaction. That means that the changes to the table are not visible until the transaction is committed.

Your code seems to be assuming that the update commits one row at a time -- that each invocation of the function sees a different version of the table. But, that is not how SQL works. While the update is executing, any reference to the table sees the "old" values. The "new" values are not apparent until the commit takes place.

Comment: Actually a transaction can see its own modifications, the issue is presumably statement level Haloween Protection.

Comment: Yes, I figured that must be the case, that changes are not visible until the update statement has completed.   So how could I write this query differently to get the results I'm looking for?     In the simple example I provided, I used 300 rows, but the real code will be updating 1000s of rows every minute.   So I'm looking for something pretty efficient.

Comment: I can get this to work by using a cursor and looping through one row at a time, but I'm thinking there has to be a more efficient faster way to accomplish this?

Comment: @JackAllen . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.  This one is amazing not clear on what the data initially looks like and how you are choosing the timestamps.  I'm pretty sure there is a better way, but the answer is very different from why your query doesn't work.